# Unity - How to find which frame my animation is on?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, frame

So I am using Unity and C# for my game. I want something to happen when the animation is on a particular frame. how do I detect what frame the animation is on?

Answer (score 2):

AnimationState.normalizedTime will give you the progress of the animation in a value between 0 and 1, you can extrapolate on this by converting it to your frame rate.

```
if (myAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime == .5f) {// the animation is halfway}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by using Animation Events.

Fist, create a function in your script to receive the event. Let's say your function is called "OnAnimationHalfWay".
[image]

Then, go to your animation and add an animation event by selecting your desired frame and clicking the "add event" button.
[image]

After that, click on the little event flag thing you just created.
[image]

Lastly, go to your inspector and in the "function" property, choose whatever the name of your function is, in my case, it's "OnAnimationHalfWay".

[image]

Hope this helped you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to happen in a particular frame you should use events on animations.

Here is the oficial documentation to achieve it:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationEventsOnImportedClips.html

In your animation, select the frame and click the event button:
[image]

(Image from https://docs.unity3d.com/)

Then you must set the function to be called. And everytime the animation goes through this frame, the function will be called.